# Reading files with DOS line endings using fgets() on linux

Tags: c, linux, file-io

I have a file with DOS line endings that I receive at run-time, so I cannot convert the line endings to UNIX-style offline. Also, my app runs on both Windows and Linux. My app does an `fgets()` on the file and tries to read in line-by-line.

Would the number of bytes read per line on Linux also account for 2 trailing characters `(\r \n)` or would it contain only *(\n)* and the *\r* would be discarded by the underlying system?

**EDIT:**

Ok, so the line endings are preserved while reading a file on Linux, but I have run into another issue. On Windows, opening the file in "r" or "rb" is behaving differently. Does windows treat these two modes distinctly, unlike Linux?

Comment: Have you actually tried using `fgets()` to read the file line by line? As far as I can remember, `fgets()` wouldn't discard the `\r` even under Windows, but under normal circumstances this shouldn't be a problem. What I would do is read the line using `fgets()` and then replace all `'\r'` and `'\n'` (which would only be at the end of the string anyways) characters with `'\0'`

Comment: @iWerner: If the file is open in binary mode, `fgets()` on Windows would read to newline (LF) and return both carriage return (CR) and LF.  If the file is open in text mode, then the ANSI C standard requires the runtime library to map the line endings from native CRLF to just LF.  This mapping means that the number of characters read into your buffer is smaller than the number of bytes in the file, which has consequences for file positioning, etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`fgets()` keeps line endings.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c37dh6kf(v=vs.80).aspx

`fgets()` itself doesn't have any special options for converting line endings, but on Windows, you can choose to either open a file in "binary" mode, or in "text" mode.  In text mode Windows converts the CR/LF sequence (C string: "\r\n") into just a newline (C string: "\n").  It's a feature so that you can write the same code for Windows and Linux and it will work (you don't need "\r\n" on Windows and just "\n" on Linux).

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/yeby3zcb(v=vs.80)

Note that the Windows call to `fopen()` takes the same arguments as the call to `fopen()` in Linux.  The "binary" mode needs a non-standard character (`'b'`) in the file mode, but the "text" mode is the default.  So I suggest you just use the same code lines for Windows and Linux; the Windows version of `fopen()` is designed for that.

The Linux version of the C library doesn't have any tricky features.  If the text file has CR/LF line endings, then that is what you get when you read it.  Linux `fopen()` will accept a `'b'` in the options, but ignores it!

http://linux.die.net/man/3/fopen

http://linux.die.net/man/3/fgets

Comment: Then I guess to be portable, one needs to set the mode to "rb" on both platforms.

Comment: For binary files, yes.  For text files, I think one should set mode "r" on both platforms; that gives text mode on Windows and lets you just check for `'\n'` instead of needing to handle `"\r\n"`.

Answer (score 3):

On Unix, the lines would be read to the newline `\n` and would include the carriage return `\r`.  You would need to trim both off the end.

Answer (score 1):

Although the other answers gave satisfying information regarind the question what kind of line ending would be returned for a `DOS` file read under `UNIX`, I'd like to mentioned an alternative way to chop off such line endings.

The significant difference is, that the following approach is multi-byte-character save, as it does not involve any characters directly:

```
if (pszLine && (2 <= strlen(pszLine)))
{ 
  size_t size = strcspn(pszLine, "\r\n"); 
  pszLine[size] = 0; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll get what's actually in the file, including the `\r` characters. In unix there aren't text files and binary files, there are just files, and stdio doesn't do conversions. After reading a line into a buffer with fgets, you can do:

```
char *p = strrchr(buffer, '\r');
if(p && p[1]=='\n' && p[2]=='\0') {
    p[0] = '\n';
    p[1] = '\0';
}
```

That will change a terminating `\r\n\0` into `\n\0`. Or you could just do `p[0]='\0'` if you don't want to keep the `\n`.

Note the use of strrchr, not strchr. There's nothing that prevents multiple `\r`s from being present in the middle of a line, and you probably don't want to truncate the line at the *first* one.

Answer to the **EDIT** section of the question: yes, the "b" in "rb" is a no-op in unix.