# fgets cannot read newline character

Tags: c, file, fgets, scanf

```
char c[500];
fgets(c, 500, fp);

if (c == "\n") {
    customer.checkoutTime = 0;
    customer.payment = 0;
}
```

I want to store two zero in these two var if fgets read a blank line. But it fail, never execute the if-block code . How should fgets read a blank line?

Comment: `c` should be an array of at least 500 `char`s, so hopefully it's not a single `char` or an uninitialised `char *`.  Also, you can't compare two strings with `==`... you need a function like `strcmp()`.

Comment: That's not how you compare strings in C! Use `strcmp(c, "\n") == 0` to test whether the string in `c` is equal to `"\n"` (replace `==` with `>=` for 'the string in `c` is greater than or equal to', etc.)

Comment: If fixing the string comparison didn't work, try verifying that you really did read a blank line (no partial line leftover from a previous read, `fp` not open in binary mode on Windows, etc.).  Check that `strlen(c)` is 1, and if not, see what's in `c`.  Also probably a good idea to check that `fgets()` succeeded first.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, a couple of things:

### 1. Function behaviour

From the [description of `fgets`](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_fgets.htm) function:

> The C library function `char *fgets(char *str, int n, FILE *stream)` reads a line from the specified stream and stores it into the string pointed to by str. It stops when either (n-1) characters are read, the newline character is read, or the end-of-file is reached, whichever comes first.

Same from `man fgets`:

> fgets() reads in at most one less than size characters from stream and stores them into the buffer pointed to by s.  Reading stops after an EOF or a newline.  If a newline is read, it is stored into the buffer.  A terminating null byte ('\0') is stored after the last character in the buffer.

#### What this means:

`fgets` *stops* reading after it encounters a `\n` (new line) character. But let's look at what we can do with the resulting string:

Given that `fgets` stops after at most N-1 characters are read, you know that, if `strlen(c)` is 499, chances are no EOF/EOL character was encountered.
If `fgets` encountered the EOL, it will return a `NULL` pointer, so you can use that. Other than that, here's how to find a new line:

Given that `c` is an array, I'd also avoid hard-coding the size of the buffer in both the declaration and the `fgets` call. Instead, I'd use:

```
char c[500], // perhaps a macro here?
    *check;
//more code
check = fgets(c, sizeof c, fp); // fgets returns relevant stuff
if (check == NULL || *check == '\0')
    //Nothing was read (EOL), or an error occurred,
    //or fgets read a nul-character at the start of the line
if (strlen(c) == (sizeof c) -1)
    //likely no EOL
else
    c[strlen(c) - 1] most likely to be EOL
```

I added the `*check == '\0'` check in response to one of chux' comments, in case `fgets` actually were to read a nul-character from the file. Since you're only interested in lines starting with a `\n`, you simply skip lines like these

---

### 2. Code issues

Apart from this, the code you posted:

```
if (c == "\n") {
```

is wrong on several levels. `"\n"` yields a pointer to a read-only string (`char *`), which will never be equal to `c`. Use `strcmp` to compare strings. For characters, use single quotes, and to compare the value(s) in `c`, you'll have to dereference it:

```
if (c[i] == '\n') // or *c == '\n'
```

In a comment to Scott Hunter's answer, you mentioned you *are* checking using `*c == '\n'`, which is fine, but `c` in that expression decays into a pointer to the first element in the array (ie the very first character read by `fgets`). It's not very likely that that character will be a new line.

Essentially, you're writing `c[0] == '\n'` whereas you should be looking at the last character (`c[strlen(c) - 1] == '\n'`) to see whether or not the string you read ends with a new line

### 3. Windows line-endings:

Most systems use `\n` for new lines. Windows uses `\r\n`. `fgets` will in fact pick up on the `\n` character, but the buffer will not be empty. The value of `c` will actually be:

```
c[500] = {'\r', '\n', 0};
```

So the first character in the string will not match `\n`. You did not specify the encoding and the system you were using (nor the compiler), but do make sure you trim any leading carriage return characters should this be required.

There's some more details on this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11305479/reading-files-with-dos-line-endings-using-fgets-on-linux)

This *could* mean that the lines you see as being empty will, from a code standpoint, not start with `\n`, but rather with `\r`. Try and check for this instead:

```
if (*c == '\r' && c[1] == '\n')
    //empty windows line
else if (*c == '\n')
    //empty *nix line
else
    //line was not empty
```

Comment: `fgets()` stops *after* reading the newline.  It *is* included in the buffer if it was large enough (and there was one to read).

Comment: Got it. I always feel difficult to understand those document. Thanks for your explanation

Comment: @Dmitri: You're right, updated (in a hurry, but emphasised the fact that newline character will be read)

Comment: `fgets()` only returns NULL if EOF was encountered *without reading anything first* (or an error occurred).  Also, encountering EOF just means reaching the end of the file/stream -- there's no "EOF character" involved.  And, I think the OP is trying to check for an *empty* line, not just a line that ends with a newline -- in which case the first char should be either `'\n'` or the terminating null character.

Comment: @Dmitri: Like I said; updated in a hurry, but if OP reads an empty line from a DOS file, it is possible for the buffer to contain both `\r` and `\n` characters, in which case: `\n` will be at offset 1, not 0

Comment: Only in binary mode, or when DOS style line endings aren't native on the platform but the file contains them anyway (though in that case, it's not actually a *blank* line...).

Comment: Avoid `c[strlen(c) - 1] == '\n'` as it is a hacker exploit.  `fgets()` can read in a null character as `c[0]` leading to a `c[SIZE_MAX]` reference.  `c[strcspn(c, "\n\r")] = 0;` is a nice alternative to lop off potential trailing end-of-line characters and then simply test `if (c[0]) ...`

Comment: @Dmitri: Yes, but OP did not provide details WRT how the file was opened or anything of the sort. Just mentioning that something worth considering

Comment: @chux: on `strlen - 1`: if `c` is empty, wouldn't `fgets` have returned a null pointer, or am I not understanding you correctly, if not: can you link me to some more info?

Comment: `fgets()` reads until encountering a `'\n'`.  It does not stop reading if it encounters a null character even though null characters are not common in a simple text file.  Consider reading `"\0xyx\n"`, `c[]` will have 5+1 characters written to it.  `strlen(c)` will return 0.  `strlen(c) - 1` will return `SIZE_MAX` as `strlen()` returns type `size_t`.  Since `fgets()` read text and did not encounter end-of-file (or error), a return of `NULL` is not expected.

Comment: @chux on my phone now, I will revisit this answer after I have had some food

Comment: There are numerous little problems with this, which add up to a biggish problem.  The only possible circumstances under which `*check == '\0'` are if there are null bytes in a text file (though text files are not supposed to contain null bytes) or if `sizeof(c) == 1` — which is a bug in the program.  Others have noted the line ending issue on platforms with native DOS-style CRLF line endings (programs reading text files should not see the CR).

Comment: @jonathanleffler nul-bytes are possible, as pointed out by chux in a comment. I agree that if `siceof c` is 1, that would be a massive issue, causing an infinite loop. CRLF line endings are visible to the program if `fp` was opened in binary mode. Considering the lack of information on this, I decided to include it in the answer

Answer (score 2):

`c` is not a single character; it is a pointer to a sequence of characters.  Your `if` is asking if that this the same location as one you have pre-filled with a newline character, which, when described that way, will obviously never succeed.

If you want to see if the first character that `c` points to is the newline character, use `if ( *c == '\n' )`.

Comment: my char is a array: char c[500]. I use *c == '\n' still get a wrong output

Comment: @ScottHunter: Yes, but the OP commented saying he is using the `*c == '\n'` now, but he's probably only checking the very first character of the string. Apart from my mistake WRT `\n` not being in the string (which I corrected), I also mention the `NULL` pointer when EOF is encountered, and the fact that OP should be looking at the _end_ of the string, not the beginning

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem: Sure, but most of that was added *after* it was accepted, and thus not part of the decision to do so.